# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.recyclerview.R$styleable

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, android-recyclerview

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.recyclerview/com.example.recyclerview.screen.HomeFragment}: **android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView**

     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
            at com.example.recyclerview.screen.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:67)

     **Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.recyclerview.R$styleable**
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:440)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:409)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:597)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:699)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
            at com.example.recyclerview.screen.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:67)
            at
```

I have added android-support-v7-recyclerview and android-support-v7-appcompat to my project but still getting this error. I'm using IDE as Intellij Idea.

Comment: show your java code and xml layout file

Comment: I solved this issue by adding classes.jar from sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/22.1.1/recyclerview-v7-22.1.1.aar_FILES location. and removed android-support-v7-recyclerview library.